# Firestore search for String in Array in Document

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, database, firebase

I want to search for an specific string value in an document which is in an array.

Here is my database:

[image: Databse]

This is my code so far: But it returns 0 documents:

```
func changePhotoUrlInPosts(url: String) {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = UserService.currentUserProfile!

    db.collection("posts")
        .whereField("username", isEqualTo: user.username)
        .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let indeedError = error {
                print(indeedError.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let indeedSnapshot = snapshot else {
                print("snapshot is empty")
                return
            }

            for document in indeedSnapshot.documents {
                document.setValue(url, forKey: "photoUrl")
            }
    }
}
```

How can I go into my array in this document?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot is showing data in Realtime Database, but your code is querying Firestore.  They are completely different databases with different APIs.  You can't use the Firestore SDK to query Realtime Database.  If you want to work with Realtime Database, use the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).

Comment: Thank you. But how to do it. Didn't found anything helpful in the Internet :(

Comment: There is lots of documentation for making queries in both databases.

Answer (score 0):

There is `author` between `posts` and `username` field in your data structure.
Your code means that right under some specific post there is `username` field.

So such code will work because `date` right undes post:

```
db.collection("posts").whereField("date", isEqualTo: "some-bla-bla-date")
```

In your case you have two options as I see:

- duplicate `username` and place this field on the same level as
  `date` and `guests`.
- re-write you code to check `username` inside `author` document.

Hope it will help you in your investigation.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed my code to:

```
func loadData(url: URL){

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    let user = UserService.currentUserProfile!

    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "author/username").queryEqual(toValue: user.username).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if var post = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            print("updated all Posts")
            post.updateValue(url.absoluteString, forKey: "photoUrl")
            print(post.values)


        }else{
            print("fail")
        }
})

}
```

It went through and I get the print statement of my values but the data didn't changed in the realtime database